# How to stream screen share video via server?

Tags: real-time, webrtc, live-streaming, screensharing

I am trying to share screen via a server. I am capturing the screencontent via webRTC and putting it inside video.

```
<video id="live" width="1280" height="960" autoplay></video>
```

Then I am drawing it inside canvas,

```
<canvas width="1280" id="canvas" height="960" style="display:none" ></canvas>
```

javascript

```
var liveVideo = $("#live").get()[0];    
var canvas = $("#canvas");
var ctx = canvas.get()[0].getContext('2d');
ctx.drawImage(liveVideo, 0, 0, 1280,960);
```

and in an interval, I am sending the base64 string of that canvas to server via socket.io, and from server i send it to all the connected clients.

The problem is, this process is very slow, I cannot do it with WebRTC peer to peer because the host will be sharing screen to a lot of clients. In that case, we are planning to set up a media streaming server with large capacity. I need to improve this and need to know the appropriate and better way to do this.

Answer (score 2):

Use webRTC to send the screensharing to the server. Then, once the webRTC communication is established between your client application and the server, multicast/broadcast it to the rest of clients. For this you will need a MCU - multipoint control unit -.

[Kurento](http://www.kurento.org/) is one of the best free source alternatives for the server side:

> Conceptually, a WebRTC media server is just a kind of “multimedia middleware” (it is in the middle of the communicating peers) where media traffic pass through when moving from source to destinations. Media servers are capable of processing media streams and offering different types including groups communications (distributing the media stream one peer generates among several receivers, i.e. acting as Multi-Conference Unit, MCU), mixing (transforming several incoming stream into one single composite stream), transcoding (adapting codecs and formats between incompatible clients), recording (storing in a persistent way the media exchanged among peers), etc.